# PIR/max-burst ignored message

Tags: networking, cisco, qos

After I typed the following `police` command for a type qos class on a Cisco Nexus 7000 switch:

```
police cir 8 kbps pir 8 kbps
```

I get the following message:

```
Note: pir/max-burst ignored
```

Can someone explain why PIR is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Because the 7K has a hard policer.  There is no notion of peak vs committed rates.  Once you pass the CIR it will start dropping packets.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is blatantly wrong.  The 7k [supports a 3-color policer](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_2/nx-os/qos/configuration/guide/policing.html#wp1056912)

Comment: My answer isn't clear enough about it, but the command he specified is one rate / two color - which means that it's a hard policer.  It breaks cir and it's a violation.  It -supports- 3-color (i.e. pir value) but it doesn't necessarily have to be configured as such.